# Prove that topologically equivalent metrics have the same open and closed sets.

Tags: real-analysis

My textbook for Real Analysis gives a pretty vague and not-so-straightforward definition of the notion of topologically equivalent metrics via open balls.

Could someone tell me what topological equivalency really means in perhaps more simple terms so I can grasp the meaning?

Comment: Are you somewhat familiar with how a metric induces a topology? Two metrics being topologically equivalent means they induce the same topology.

Comment: Unfortunately, we didn't learn how a metric induces a topology.

Comment: It's easy, just take balls of positive radius as neighborhoods of the center.

Comment: One simple way to say it is that two metrics $d$ and $d'$ on a space $X$ are topologically equivalent provided that the identity map $Id \colon (X,d) \to (X,d')$ is a homeomorphism.  In other words, every open set for $d$ is an open set for $d'$ and vice-versa.

Comment: You should perhaps provide your text's definition of "topologically equivalent metrics".

Comment: I guess his definition is something like balls in one metric contain a ball of the other and vice versa.

Comment: @user2345215, that was really the definition provided in the textbook. They used open balls involving s = s(r,x) > 0, where r > 0.

Comment: I can't figure out a way to prove this problem fully. For open sets, the proof seems simpler because the definition only uses open balls as subsets of other open balls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple definition of topologically equivalent metrics is that the topologies they induce are equal. That just means a set is open in one metric if and only if it's open in the other metric.

The topology induced by a metric $\mu$ is simple, you call a set $G$ open if and only if $(\forall x\in G)(\exists B_\mu(x,r))\ B_\mu(x,r)\subseteq G$. That is, for every point in the set there's an open ball contained in the set.

Suppose you have a set $G$ open in $\mu$, then for every $x\in G$ there exists a ball $B_\mu(x,r_x)\subseteq G$. This implies that $G=\bigcup\limits_{x\in G}B_\mu(x,r_x)$. So it's a union of open balls around its every point.

If metrics $\mu_0$ and $\mu_1$ are topologically equivalent by your definition then for any set $G$ open in $\mu_0$ we have $G=\bigcup\limits_{x\in G}B_{\mu_0}(x,r_x)\supseteq\bigcup\limits_{x\in G}B_{\mu_1}(x,s_x)\supseteq G$, so $G=\bigcup\limits_{x\in G}B_{\mu_1}(x,s_x)$ and even in $\mu_1$ there's an open ball contained in $G$ around every point of $G$ which means $G$ is open in $u_1$.

The same argument shows every set open in $\mu_1$ is also open in $\mu_0$.